Two Squid Chaining but different IP segment
Can two proxy servers be chained together, where one server has access to the internet and the other can only access internal networks? How can I configure this setup?
IP addresses information:

ProxyA - 192.168.0.100 (Without internet access) and 10.10.100.115 (Internet access)
ProxyB - 192.168.1.100
Client - 192.168.1.10

Proxy A can ping Proxy B using the 192.168 segment. The client will only connect to ProxyB, which is an internal proxy, but will need to access the internet. Is it possible to set up this configuration?

welcome, had you a chance to read the manual??
